# Audio Devise Selection Dialogue Stopped Working on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, devices, audio-jack

While there are a ton of questions (all well answered) about the exact opposite -- i.e. how to get rid of the audio device selection dialogue box when plugging in a new audio device -- I have lost that dialogue box somehow and would like it back.  I liked the audio device selection pop-up on plug in ... and suddenly it just stopped.  Its not a massive error as Ubuntu is still recognizing something is plugged in, and I can go to sound settings and select what I want and it works fine, but I dislike having to go to sound settings every single time I plug or unplug something as the nature of my setup and work causes this to happen a large number of times each day.

I honestly have no idea why it just stopped working.  Unless is it maybe associated with the ibus-deamon?  I did monkey with that.

Since this all happened I have tried some updates with apt and such but it hasn't changed the behavior at all.